# cant save pattern matches in array using perl and regex

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

I am trying to save matched patterns in an array using perl and regex, the problem is that when the match is saved it is missing some characters

ex:

```
my @array;
my @temp_array;
@types_U8 = ("uint8","vuint8","UCHAR");
foreach my $type (@types_U8)
{
 @temp_array = $str =~ /\(\s*\Q$type\E\s*\)\s*(0x[0-9ABCDEF]{3,}|\-[1-9]+)/g;
 push(@array,@temp_array);
 @temp_array = ();
}
```

So if `$str = "any text (uint8)-1"`

The saved string in the `@temp_array` is only ever "-1"

Comment: What are you expecting the match to be?

Comment: @ Hunter McMillen iam expecting (uint8)-1

Comment: Well your capture group doesn't include $type, so you will never get the (uint8) piece.

Comment: what is the capture group , could you clarify more

Comment: The capture group is *most* things in your regular expression that are surrounded by parens e.g `(...)`. These captures will be what is returned to your `@temp_array`.

Comment: so i just enclose the whole regex in parens like that `(\(\s*\Q$type\E\s*\)\s*(0x[0-9ABCDEF]{3,}|\-[1-9]+))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current regular expression is:

```
/\(\s*\Q$type\E\s*\)\s*(0x[0-9ABCDEF]{3,}|\-[1-9]+)/g
```

this means

1. match a literal left paren: `\(`
2. match zero or more whitespace characters:  `\s*`
3. match the value that is stored in `$type`: `\Q$type\E`
4. match zero of more whitespace characters: `\s*`
5. match a literal right paren: `\)`
6. match zero of more whitespace characters: `\s*`
7. START capturing group: `(`
8. match a 3 digit hexadecimal number prefixed with 0x
    OR
   match a literal dash, followed by 1 or more digits from 1 to 9: `0x[0-9ABCDEF]{3,}|\-[1-9]+`
9. END capturing group: `)`

If you notice above, your capturing group doesn't start until step #7, when you would also like to capture `$type` and the literal parens.

Extend your capturing group to enclose those areas:

```
/(\(\s*\Q$type\E\s*\)\s*(?:0x[0-9ABCDEF]{3,}|\-[1-9]+))/;
```

This means:

1. START a capturing group: `(`
2. match a literal left paren: `\(`
3. match zero or more whitespace characters: `\s*`
4. match the value that is stored in `$type`: `\Q$type\E`
5. match zero of more whitespace characters: `\s*`
6. match a literal right paren: `\)`
7. match zero of more whitespace characters: `\s*`
8. START non-capturing group: `(?:`
9. match a 3 digit hexadecimal number prefixed with 0x
    OR
   match a literal dash, followed by 1 or more digits from 1 to 9: `0x[0-9ABCDEF]{3,}|\-[1-9]+`
10. END non-capturing group: `)`
11. END capturing group: `)`

(Note: I removed the `g` (global) modifier because it is unnecessary)

This change gives me a result of `(uint8)-1`